# Load a TinyMCE editor inside a TinyMCE modal in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE to open a modal. And inside that modal i would want to add an instance of tinyMCE. I'm opening the modal [passing some objects](http://johnmorris.me/computers/using-jquery-and-jquery-ui-in-tinymce-dialog-iframe/). I followed [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815193906/http://johnmorris.me/computers/software/how-to-create-a-tinymce-editor-dialog-window-in-a-wordpress-plugin/)

```
            editor.windowManager.open(
                //  Properties of the window.
                {
                    title: "TDSK's Dumb Shortcode Creator",   //    The title of the dialog window.
                    file:  url + '/tinymce-dialog.html',      //    The HTML file with the dialog contents.
                    width: 1000,                               //    The width of the dialog
                    height: 600,                              //    The height of the dialog
                    inline: 1                                 //    Whether to use modal dialog instead of separate browser window.
                },

                //  Parameters and arguments we want available to the window.
                {
                    editor: editor,   //    This is a reference to the current editor. We'll need this to insert the shortcode we create.

                    jquery: $,        //    If you want jQuery in the dialog, you must pass it here.
                    tinymce: tinymce
                }
            );
```

In the tinymce-dialog.html

```
var passed_arguments = top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams();
var $ = passed_arguments.jquery;

var jq_context = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
$( function() {
    passed_arguments.tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, $( '#sectionContent_1', jq_context )[0] );
} );
```

This actually creates an instance of TinyMce which is not working though

[image]

probably the reason is an error

> TypeError: elm is undefined

which points to

```
    aria: function(name, value) {
        var self = this, elm = self.getEl(self.ariaTarget);

        if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            return self._aria[name];
        }

        self._aria[name] = value;

        if (self.state.get('rendered')) {
            elm.setAttribute(name == 'role' ? name : 'aria-' + name, value);
        }

        return self;
    },
```

what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe if you run with a non minified version of tinymce it might be clearer what the error is!

Comment: @dev-nullyeah trying to do that

Comment: @dev-null done, sorry i didn't do this earlier

Comment: If you look at the call stack what is it saying? And what about line number etc... Try adding a conditional breakpoint at that line (`!elm`). This will stop your code just before the error occurs. Now you can look back in the call stack.

Comment: @dev-null I copied the function. I wonder if the instance of tinymce editor i use in the dialog has jQuery referencing the parent window

Comment: `self.ariaTarget` is somehow not set correct

Comment: @dev-null I know but this probably has to do with the fact that i pass TinyMce, jQuery for example points to the main page http://johnmorris.me/computers/using-jquery-and-jquery-ui-in-tinymce-dialog-iframe/

Comment: where does ariaTarget come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to stop using TinyMce modal and use bootstrap modals.

Comment: can you share how you did this with a bootstrap model .. i'd also like to attach a tinymce editor to a textbox within a bootstrap modal panel